# Passar a senha do certificado v

Tags: c#

Boa tarde, estou desenvolvendo um sistema onde utiliza certificado pfx, como mostra o código abaixo eu passo o diretório onde ele se encontra, mas não consigo passar a senha como parâmetro, o principal objeto do meu sistema é pegar a validade do certificado.

```
public void ctf()
{

    // Caminho do certificado
    string Certificate = "C: CERTIFICADO.PFX";


    // Carregar o certificado em um objeto X509Certificate
    X509Certificate cert = X509Certificate.CreateFromCertFile(Certificate);

    // pega o valor( validade)
    string results = cert.GetExpirationDateString();

    // Exibe
    Console.WriteLine(results);

}
```